# detect man in the middle attacks by seeing if the issue is from a non trusted CA

Tags: azure, security, ssl

I would appreciate any help or guidance with these questions:
My customer is using an opened server for an app hosted in Azure. (at login.microsoftonline.com)

The host started providing different certificates issued by different CA:

**Old certificate:**

```
Issuer: C=US, O=Symantec Corporation, OU=Symantec Trust Network, CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
```

**New certificate sometimes returned:**

```
Issuer: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
```

The customer gets the certificate info by using an OpenSSL command (dumping the certificate details of the host).

They need some clarification about the behavior of this host: 
In case a client will whitelist only the needed Certification Authority, which is the list of the certificate that such host could expose?
Is such list supposed to be stable or might change?
Since this host is producer of crucial security data they would like to understand how to identify it in a secure way ( without the risk of exposing the communication to a man-in-the-middle attack)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The owner of a domain decides which CA to use for the certificates belonging to the domain. Thus you would need to ask the owner of the domain (i.e. Microsoft in this case) which CA they plan to use in the future.

Right now it looks like that Microsoft is using sub-CA "Microsoft IT SSL SHA2" which is is owned by Microsoft itself. This sub-CA itself is not trusted by any browsers but it is signed by the root CA "Baltimore CyberTrust Root" which then is in the browsers trust store. But this might change, i.e. Microsoft might decide to use a different sub-CA which then might be issued by a different root CA. Ask them about their future plans.

Comment: Thank you Steffen!
So it is safe to assume that the behavior that we previously observed (2 different CAs used in parallel ) was a fault.
Can we assume that starting from now, this host will only replay with a unique CA (Baltimore CyberTrust Root right now)?

Comment: @Razvan: it is likely that Microsoft will not change the CA again in the next weeks or month. It is also likely that Microsoft will change the CA again within the next years. Again, that's fully up to Microsoft which CA it chooses for it's domain.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sorry it was of a similar context. I deleted it.